# why pyinstaller available in virtual environment even I did not install it

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, pyinstaller, virtual-environment

I created a python virtual environment by virtualenv and activate it, then I found I can use pyinstaller in this vir-env, but I had not "pip install pyinstaller" in it, why? And as comparison, I wrote 'import <not_installed_module>' in code, then it threw up 'module unfound' and it is as expected.

---- updated 1st ----
thanks to reminder, added my operation
[image]

---- updated 2nd -----
thanks to comments, it shows the pyinstaller is still in system path
[image]

Comment: how you know it's part of virtualenv and not your system-wide installed one?

Comment: Yeah as @MarcinOrlowski said, you might be calling your system-wide interpreter, use `whereis python` (for linux) or `where python` (for windows) to see where your different python interpreters are. Then call pyinstaller as so `{path/to/desired/interpreter/python.exe} -m PyInstaller {args}`. Note that it's important to write `PyInstaller` and not `pyinstaller` when calling it this way.
Hope this helps !

Comment: a note: on linux you'd rather use `which` which will show you which exact binary will be used if invoked without full path, while `whereis` will show more items, which might be confusing

Comment: Good call, my bad, I'm not as good with linux cli as I'd like to be xD

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all comments, they help me get the answer:

when I enter vir-env, and not install pyinstaller, I run `where pyinstaller` (win-10) and get the system-wide installed one:

> C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe

then I install pyinstaller in vir-env by `pip install pyinstaller`, and run `where pyinstaller`, I get two:

> (prj_path)\.venv\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe
> C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe

now I run "pyinstaller ..." It calls the pyinsaller in vir-env